# Macro for button to today's sheet in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to know if it is possible to make a macro link to open a sheet named "Today()"? I have a Workbook with sheets named according to dates along with a "Home" sheet and "Month End" sheet. There is a Macro which copies the last sheet to create a new sheet for today with balance values from yesterday's sheet. I want to add a button on each sheet that would revert me back to the sheet named with today's date.

Here is my code

```
Sub TodaySheet()

Dim FindName As String, FindSheet As Worksheet

    For Each FindSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        If FindSheet.Name = "Today()" Then
            FindSheet.Activate
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Hope I'm on the right track?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: can you please assist me with he coding for it? thank you

Comment: Use the search engine of your choice and search for `How to start VBA`. As soon as you got through the first tutorials, start writing your code. If you get stuck, update your question with the lines of code you are stuck at, and we will help you. Good luck!

Comment: No, I will not code it for you, that is not what this site is for.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me, teach me to code, or show me where to start site.

Comment: Is the sheet *literally* named `Today()`, or is it today's date, i.e. `21/08/2017`?

Comment: And my question now is what is wrong with the code, what error do you get when you run it?

Comment: The sheets are named "21-08-2017",  "20-08-2017" and so on the code does not want to except the sheet naming "Today()"

Comment: I need it to be working/ auto updating to go to the current date's sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to iterate through the worksheets, although it will work. You can ".Activate" the desired one directly, in one statement.